# Access a method from another class

Tags: java, class, methods

I made a third class as you recommended like this!!

```
public class WebSocket_Connector {

private static final String TAG = "ECHOCLIENT";
public final WebSocketConnection mConnection = new WebSocketConnection();

public void connect(final String wsuri) {

      Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to: " + wsuri); 

      try {
         mConnection.connect(wsuri, new WebSocketHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onOpen() {
               Log.d(TAG, "Status: Connected to " + wsuri ); 
               Log.d(TAG, "Connection successful!\n");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextMessage(String payload) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Got echo: " + payload);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Connection closed.");
            }
         });
      } catch (WebSocketException e) {

         Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
      }
   }
```

}

And from another class, I am trying to access the connect passing the string type "id"

```
public class Myoffers_Fragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "ECHOCLIENT";
public String id;

public static Fragment newInstance(Myoffers context, int pos, 
        float scale)
{
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("pos", pos);
    b.putFloat("scale", scale);
    return Fragment.instantiate(context, Myoffers_Fragment.class.getName(), b);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    WebSocket_Connector A = new WebSocket_Connector();

    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) 
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.mf, container, false);

    int pos = this.getArguments().getInt("pos");
    TextView tv = (TextView) l.findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText("Position = " + pos);

    ImageView product_photo = (ImageView) l.findViewById(R.id.myoffer_image);

    switch(pos){
    case 0:
        product_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_0);
        Log.d(TAG, "Current pos" + pos);
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Product" + pos + " is selected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        id = "product 0";
        A.mConnection.sendTextMessage(id);
        break;
```

Can you see the "A.mConnection.sendTextMessage(id);" ??
Is it right way to do it?

Comment: why didnt this question show any effor??? I looked for other questions and those couldnt manage my problem!

Comment: First, no where does `mConnection` is declared. Second, you don't show the code for `sendTextMessage(id)`, which could be a nonexistent method for all we know. Third, where is `id` declared? Clarify your question and you might get help. From a comment on a answer, shouldn't this be tagged Android also?

Comment: There is mConnection and sendTextMessage(id) and id declared.

Comment: And what is the error you're getting? Compile time, in your IDE? It's still unclear what kind of help is needed. As far as I can tell, you never call `connect` on `A`, which might be why `sendTextMessage` doesn't work.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau In the Connector class, it produces "WebSocketConnection" Class which is included in library jar files. And I want to access the "WebSocketConnection" through "Connector" class from another class. And I want to ask how can I access the "WebSocketConnection" from another class? Is it clear ?

Comment: I don't see `A.connect()` call anywhere, and `A.mConnection.sendTextMessage()` annihilates encapsulation. I recommend that you read some Java and Object Oriented Programming books or texts before attempting any serious programming.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an instance of your class in order to access its public methods. Considering your connect method is within your main class you would have to declare: `Main main = new Main();` (also side note, you should always capitalize your class names). Then call `main.connect();`.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to do that to Android `Activity` classes. Probably the best thing to do is to move connect to a third utility class you can instantiate, and use it from both `main` and `Myoffers_Fragment` classes.

Comment: it's not working. I added, main Main = new main(); and Main.connect(); but second one makes an error.

Comment: @vhallac what do you mean move to a third utility class?

Comment: @vhallac I totally agree.

Comment: @JungHur `public class Connector { public void connect() { ... } }` kind of thing. A third class that manages connections. Good for separation of concerns as well.

Comment: @JungHur Are you passing a String url into your connect? It should be class.connect(yourString);

Comment: Yes, I am trying to pass the String type "id" to connect!

Comment: @vhallac I edited the question. Can you check it please?

Comment: @Max Yes, I made third class as a connector and from another class, im trying to pass the string type id to connector class. is it right?

Comment: @JungHur You have no method called mConnection under your websocket class. You only have a connect method.

Comment: @Max mConnection is included in the Library jar files!! But, I cant access mConnection from main class!!

Comment: @Max in the Connector class, it produces "WebSocketConnection" Class which is included in library jar files. And I want to access the "WebSocketConnection" through "Connector" class from another class.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be self explanatory

```
 class A {
    public void someMethod(){
       System.out.println("in someMethod");
    }
 }

 public class B {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        A a = new A(); // first create the object of class A
        a.someMethod();// call its method in class B
    }

 }
```

Comment: As you mentioned, I put "main a = new main(); and a.connect();, but second one makes an error.